# How to use calculated field in another field of the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a select query with a few dozen fields.  "FieldA" is a Case statement about 10 rows tall.  I now have to make a "FieldB" which uses the same Case statement plus a constant.

With my current knowledge of sql-server, I'd have to repeat that Case statement twice (once for FieldA and once for FieldB).  To clean up my code, how can I use fieldA in the calculation of FieldB?

Ideally, my code would look something like this:

```
Select
    Case ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
    End                     as FieldA,
    FieldA + 1              as FieldB
From TblSource
```

(I know that one option is to dump the data into a temporary table, then update that temp table.  But that kind of defeats the concept of 'simplifying')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
;WITH YourCTE AS
(
Select
    Case ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
    End                     as FieldA
From TblSource
)
SELECT FieldA, FieldA + 1 AS FieldB, FieldA + 2 AS FieldC ....
FROM YourCTE
```

Comment: It works! Not as simple as I was hoping for (it basically splits 1 Select statement into 2), but it has a few advantages of it's own.

Comment: Wonder if it the only solution?

Answer (score 3):

@Johnny_D

There's always the possibility of using the following

```
Select tbl.*,tbl.FieldA+1 as FieldB, tbl.FieldA+2 as FieldC from
(
Select
    Case ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
        When ... then ...
    End as FieldA
From TblSource
) as tbl
```

Comment: That works too.  And since it doesn't use the (relatively obscure) `; With` command, it's easier to explain.