# Referencing a column in a SELECT from another column in that SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I haven't found a way to do this yet, but I figured I'd check in case I'm missing something.

What I'm wanting to do is basically:

```
SELECT st.SomeIntValue AS Column1, Column1 * 10 AS Column2, Column2 * 3 AS Column3
FROM SomeTable st
```

Is there some way to do this in SQL Server, without resorting to nested sub-queries?

**Edit:**
Example to make it more clear why I'm doing this.
I need to do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (ThisThingIsTrue
                  AND ThisOtherThingIsTrue) THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0
       END AS Concept1,
       CASE WHEN (ThisThingIsTrue
                  AND ThisOtherThingIsTrue) THEN 0
                                            ELSE 1
       END AS UnrelatedConcept2,
FROM SomeTable
```

This code goes into a view, and the problem is that code using this view just wants to know the value of UnrelatedConcept2 - it would be confusing for the client code to derive UnrelatedConcept2 by specifying NOT Concept1. And it would be nice to not have to repeat the CASE WHEN statement when I could just NOT the value of Concept1.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I dont think there is a way, but honestly what your trying to do doesnt make any sense. could you provide example data data set and expected results

Comment: chances are you will have to re-calculate your base value (column1) in each of the column values. example `select st.SomeIntValue as Column1, (st.SomeIntValue * 10) as Column2, ...` if this helps let me know to include it as an Answer

Comment: @thermite I added an example above - hopefully the why should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are trying to use a calculated value in the same query. If that's the question, someone answered it here: [How to use calculated field in another field of the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511982/how-to-use-calculated-field-in-another-field-of-the-same-query)

Comment: Ok, it looks like this will work. Missed this question when searching for related questions.